# how to extract only some values from a table in dynamodb from a data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a table in dynamoDB. I want to backup only some particular records to S3. Is there anyway to do that using DataPipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the stream on your DynamoDB table and attach a lambda function to it that selectively persists newly created items, updates and deletions to S3.

Comment: oh..thanks. That's another way. Surely will check it out. I found another way, where you can use hive to fetch data based on sql queries.